# Display none after css animation ended

Tags: css, animation, time, css-animations, display

I have a working animation that starts on load with pure CSS. The problem with both `opacity` and `visibility` is that even if the div is hidden, it still takes up space.

### Question

How can I make the div disapear like `display: none` after the animation is done?

### Notes

- I would prefer to have a pure CSS solution. The less hackish solution, the better.
- I've seen similar questions, but not exactly this case and no good answers for this problem.
- I use `animation` and not `transition` because it animates on load.

```css
.message.success {
  background: #28a745;
  color: #fff;
  animation: autohide 2s forwards;
  padding: 1rem;
}

@keyframes autohide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="message success">
  Success!
</div>

This text below is expected to jump up after animation is done.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `height` property to achieve this effect:

```css
@keyframes autohide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    height: auto;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

`height` is kept `auto` until near the end of the animation (99%), then set to `0` as it completes.

Comment: It works, as long as there is no padding. If there is padding, it will still take up some of the space.

Comment: Can you set the padding to zero as soon as the animation hits 100%?

Comment: Yes, that worked! I set the padding on 99% and then to 0 at 100%. Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could set to zero the padding and the font-size at the last keyframe

```css
.message.success {
  background: #28a745;
  color: #fff;
  animation: autohide 2s forwards;
  padding: 1rem;
}

@keyframes autohide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  85% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  95% {  
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: inherit;
  }
  100% {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="message success">
  Success!
</div>

This text below is expected to jump up after animation is done.
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go i think this is what you want.

> By giving `height` to `0` works perfectly with `transition`

```css
.message.success {
  background: #28a745;
  color: #fff;
  animation: autohide 2s forwards;
  transition: height 2s ease;
}

@keyframes autohide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="message success">
  Success!
</div>

This text below is expected to jump up after animation is done.
```

*You can play with transition as per req.*

Comment: Yes it works. What I forgot in my snippet was that I also have padding. With padding this solution only remove a part of the space. I've updated my question.

Comment: Oh NP it happens! set `padding` as well in `animation` form `max` to `min`